# States angularjs $stateProvider not passing arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I got a current angularjs application using the standard $routeProvider for routing. I intend to use a part of the application the $stateProvider for a wizard.

I declared a parent state 'Modal' and a child state 'editClient' like this:

```
    $stateProvider.state('Modal', {
        views: {
            'modal': {
                templateUrl: '*urlHere*',
                controller: '*controllerHere'
            }
        },
        abstract: true
    });

    $stateProvider.state('Modal.editClient', {
        views: {
            "modal": {
                url: '/editClient/:id',
                templateUrl: '*templateHere*',
                controller: '*controllerHere*'
            }
        }
    });
```

In my controller I call:

```
$state.go('Modal.editClient', { id: 1});
```

Yet $stateParams is empty. How come?

I'm using angular-ui-router version 0.2.15 and angularjs 1.2.25. Updating to a higher angularjs version is not possible at the moment.

**Update**

I also tried:

```
    $stateProvider.state('Modal.editClient', {
        views: {
            "modal": {
                params: {
                    'id' : 0
                },
                templateUrl: '*templateUrlHere*',
                controller: '*controllerHere*'
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `url` does not go in `views`

Comment: so I removed url. and added the params into the state declaration. Still doesn't give me any id in the $stateParams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing argument in state where you are defining your states you need to do something like this.

```
 $stateProvider.state('Modal', {
        views: {
            'modal': {
                templateUrl: '*urlHere*',
                controller: '*controllerHere'
            }
        },
        abstract: true
    });

    $stateProvider.state('Modal.editClient', {
       params: {
                        'id': 0
                },
        views: {
            "modal": {
                url: '/editClient/:id',
                templateUrl: '*templateHere*',
                controller: '*controllerHere*'
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Tried, with and without the url property. Still doesn't give me any id to work with. Even when a value is declared.

Comment: have u tried with params: {
                  'id': 0
              }, ? try with new edited params

Comment: Yep replacing the location of params made it work. Thank you for the help.